# Delete all rows after a certain Row found on another sheet

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a VBA to delete all rows past a certain number found within my workbook.  For example my (certain row number is found on sheet 1 in cell B6) The VBA would delete all rows on sheet 2 starting at the row number found on sheet 1 B6.  This is what I have so far, but obviously doesn't work

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Worksheets("sheet 2").Rows($B$6 & ":" & Worksheets("sheet 2").Rows.Count).Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("B" & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B6") & ":B" & Worksheets("Sheet 2").Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
```

Would get you specifically what you're asking for, but you should ask yourself if it's really efficient to be deleting upwards of 1,000,000 rows. Could you identify the last used row in `Worksheets("Sheet 2")` by utilizing an `(xlUp)` or `(xlDown)` method to define a much smaller range to delete?

```
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("B" & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B6") & ":B" & Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Delete
```

Additionally, judging by your usage, your only purpose for deleting these rows is to clear the contents, in which case using `.ClearContents` as opposed to `.Delete` would be faster still.